# Yii error summary default message change

Tags: php, error-handling, yii

Hi am not very familiar with Yii framework, Can someone show me how to change the default errorSummary message? I've already looked at the Yii guide and confused me. What do I need to add to my model and what I need in the view? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have? We will then have a look at it and show you where you have made the mistake. StackOverflow is not a community that serves you code on request. It's a community that helps you improve your existing code and **helps** you solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the default message to the rules section of your model as shown below

```
public function rules()
    {
array('attrubutename', 'required','message' => 'Your message'),
        }
```

**UPDATED** try this

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model,'Your message goes here'); ?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I mean how to change the default errorSummary message..
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
not:
<?php echo $form->error($model,'attibutename'); ?>

Comment: Change means what do u want to achieve ?? The format or the content inside it ??

Comment: I mean the default message comes out as:
Please fix the following input errors:
followed by a list of all errors set by what your answer would do.
what I want to change is the Please fix the following input errors.
this message.
sorry if am confusing

Comment: Hi sorry I dont have enough reputation to vote answer up. I just joined the site.. :(